# useState in multiple variants loop not working - React with NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-state

I have multiple variants in my one component, and I want that if I click on any variant it should add active class to it and removes active class from another. But I am stuck how it can happen using state in multiple variants loop.
**Here is my code:**

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Variants = () => {
    // Sample Variants Object - But in real it's coming from Wordpress back-end GraphQL
    const vats = {
        "Tech": ['3G', '5G'],
        "Color": ['Red', 'Gray']
    }

    const [selectedTech, techToChange] = useState(null);

    return (
        <div>
            {vats && (
                <div>
                    {Object.keys(vats).map((key, value) => (
                        <div key={key}>
                            <div><b>{key}</b></div>
                            {vats[key].map((val) => (
                                <div key={val} onClick={() => techToChange('active')}>
                                    <label
                                        className="cursor-pointer bg-yellow-100"
                                    >
                                        {val} - {selectedTech}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                            <hr/>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            )}
            <hr />
        </div>
    )
}
```

You can see in my code, there are 2 variants named `Tech & Color`, For example; If I click on `3G` of tech, it should add active class to it and removes active class from `5G` & If I click on `Red` it should add active class to it and removes active class from `Gray`. Can someone please help me to do it? I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just setting `selectedTech` to `'active'`–this is just a string and doesn't create any sort of relationship between the tech clicked and the `selectedTech` in state.

To fix this, you need to set the `selectedTech` to the actual `val` of the one you clicked. To add the variant separation you want, the state can mimic the shape of your variants and be an object. So instead of setting `selectedTech` directly, you can set `selectedTech[variant]` to the value you clicked.

And then, with a little evaluation, you can print out the string, `active` when you click on one.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  // Sample Variants Object - But in real it's coming from Wordpress back-end GraphQL
    const vats = {
    Tech: ["3G", "5G"],
    Color: ["Red", "Gray"]
  };
  const initialState = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(vats).map((key)=> [key, null]));  const [selectedTech, techToChange] = useState(initialState);

  return (
    <div>
      {vats && (
        <div>
          {Object.keys(vats).map((key, value) => (
            <div key={key}>
              <div>
                <b>{key}</b>
              </div>
              {vats[key].map((val) => (
                <div key={val} onClick={() => techToChange((c) => ({...c, [key]: val}))}>
                  <label className="cursor-pointer bg-yellow-100">
                    {val} - {selectedTech[key] === val ? "active" : null}
                  </label>
                </div>
              ))}
              <hr />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-kare-hsphp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: No bro, It's not working fine. If I click on `3G` from `Tech` variant, it's also removing class from `Color` variants.

Comment: That's pretty good, but it seems like something hardcoded in `useState()`. Because Variants are coming from WordPress Database, and there are a lot of products with different names & multiple variants. It can be 2, 3 or 4, even their names. So how can i set that in `useState()`?

Comment: O I got it, solved now. I put the `vats` variable in `useState` like `useState([vats])` & it's working perfect now

Comment: A more long-term solution could be using `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.keys` to create an object like the one I had hardcoded but based on the incoming data: `const initialState = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(vats).map((key)=> [key, null]));`

Comment: That's also pretty cool. Thanks bro for this

Comment: Bro, can you please tell me what is this line doing? I mean i didn't understand what's going on here and what actually it is doing and how. `(c) => ({...c, [key]: val}))`

Comment: 1. `Object.keys` returns an array of object keys (`['Tech', 'Color']`)
2. [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) takes an array of arrays ([ [key, value] ]) and turns it into an object.
3. (c) => ({ ...c, [key]: val})  is [a callback for setstate](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback) that helps you safely merge state objects (among other things).

Comment: No no, I am not talking about first 2 points. I am talking about the 3rd point, the `c` variable, what is in the `c` variable? and the next `{ ...c, [key]: val }`, what it is doing

Comment: (c) => ({ ...c, [key]: val}) is a [callback for setstate](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback) that helps you safely merge state objects (among other things). `c` refers to the current state (whatever `selectedTech` is at the time that state update runs). I'm returning an object, spreading the current `c` state, and then updating the `key` property to whatever value the user clicked. So if you clicked 5G, it would evaluate as `{ ...c, Tech: '5G' }` essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the return code. You need to pass the val to set the state of `selectedTech` state variable and then compare the actual value with it to have the active class set.

```
const [selectedTech, techToChange] = useState([]);

    const selectOps = (key,val) => {
        let existing = selectedTech;
        let idx = existing.findIndex(i => i.key===key);
        console.log(idx);
        
        if(idx > -1){
         existing.splice(idx,1);
         console.log(idx, existing);
        }
        techToChange([...existing, {key,val}]);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {vats && (
                <div>
                    {Object.keys(vats).map((key, value) => (
                        <div key={key}>
                            <div><b>{key}</b></div>
                            {vats[key].map((val) => (
                                <div key={val} onClick={() => selectOps(key,val)}>
                                    <label
                                        className={`cursor-pointer bg-yellow-100 ${selectedTech.some(s => s.val===val) ? 'active' : undefined}`}
                                    >
                                        {val}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                            <hr/>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            )}
            <hr />
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: It's not working fine. If I click on `3G` from `Tech` variant, it's also removing class from `Color` variants.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. Hope you'll figure it out

Answer (score 0):

[`useMap`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useMap.md) from `react-use` would fit nicely in to your existing code:

```
const [vats, {set, setAll, remove, reset}] = useMap({
    "Tech": ['3G', '5G'],
    "Color": ['Red', 'Gray']
}
...

{Object.keys(vats).map((key, value) => (

...
     <div key={val} onClick={() => set(key, val)}>
```

Comment: react-use is not working. I've installed `react-use` and even restarted my project but still it says `Error: Cannot find module 'react-use'`

Comment: @ZainShabir did you install it? It's not part of React, see [here](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/Usage.md).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using useRef and some other stuff that you might find useful:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect} from "react";

const Variants = () => {
// Sample Variants Object - But in real it's coming from Wordpress back- 
end GraphQL
const vats = {
    "Tech": ['3G', '5G'],
    "Color": ['Red', 'Gray']
}

const labelRef = useRef();
const [selectedTech, techToChange] = useState("");
const [selectedColor, colorToChange] = useState("");

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(selectedColor);
  if(labelRef.current.innerHTML.trim() === selectedColor) {
    labelRef.current.className ="other class";
  }
  else {
    labelRef.current.className ="cursor-pointer bg-yellow-100";
  }
},
[selectedColor, labelRef])

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(selectedTech);
  if(labelRef.current.innerHTML.trim() === selectedTech) {
    labelRef.current.className ="other class";
  }
  else {
    labelRef.current.className ="cursor-pointer bg-yellow-100";
  }
},
[selectedTech, labelRef])


return (
    <div>
        {vats && (
            <div>
                {Object.keys(vats).map((key, value) => (
                    <div key={key}>
                        <div><b>{key}</b></div>
                        {vats[key].map((val) => (
                            <div key={val} onClick={(e) => {
                              
                              if(key==="Tech") {
                             //console.log(e.target.innerHTML); 
                             techToChange(e.target.innerHTML.trim());
                             labelRef.current = e.target;
                             //console.log(val.trim(),selectedTech.trim());
                              }
                              else if(key==="Color")
                              {
                              colorToChange(e.target.innerHTML.trim())
                              labelRef.current = e.target;
                              }
                            }
                             
                            }>
                              
                                <label ref={labelRef}
                                    className="cursor-pointer bg-yellow-100"
                                >{val}                                                                     
                                </label>
                              
                            </div>
                        ))}
                        <hr/>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )}
        <hr />
    </div>
)
}

export default Variants;
```